# Fingerprint login in 20.10 doesn't work

Tags: login, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader, 20.10

Fresh Ubuntu 20.10 on Lenovo T14 Gen1,
I followed tutorial https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-fingerprint.html.en
(however process is a bit buggy... when i register new finger, you need to touch sensor few times,  i can touch sensor with different fingers every time and there is no info that something is wrong)

after adding one or two fingers, i can't login with fingerprint. There is a message on login screen that I can scan my finger, but when i scan it, nothing happens ...

Comment: ah, it looks like it was enough to enable auth thru `pam-auth-update` program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had to run `pam-auth-update` program and enable auth thru fingerprint there.
Now it works

Answer (score 0):

> it was enough to enable auth thru `pam-auth-update` program

I appreciate you answering your own question @razor.  I had fingerprint login working on 19.10, then 20.04 on my Dell XPS 13, although it only worked about 65% of the time.  But then I upgraded to 20.10 and, though I was able to easily add more fingerprint profiles, I could never login.  In fact, it didn't eve me any indication it was checking my fingerprint.  Anyway, your answer did the trick!  I don't know why I had to do it now and not earlier, but I appreciate you sharing the info.